# I can't get the firstChild element on my youtube notifications popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension.
I try to create a div and put it at the top of my notifications popup on youtube that we open by clicking on [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lqoa.png).

So I try to catch the first child of my container and make a insertBefore.
But I have a problem : I can't get the firstChild element of my container, or it is always null.

I try this code, but I don't know if it's the good way :

```js
const notificationsContainer = document.querySelector("#container > #sections");
notificationsContainer.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; //to view my container

/* Creation of my new div */
let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
newDiv.style.height = "50px";
newDiv.style.width = "50px";
newDiv.style.top = "0";

/* Insert my newDiv */
let parentElement = document.querySelector("#items");
let childElement = parentElement.firstChild;
parentElement.insertBefore(newDiv, childElement);
```

This is when I print my parentElement and childElement in the console (they are empty) : [console print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKbr1.png)

Thank you for your help !

*P.S.*
I'm trying to get my notifications so I scrap them with js, if you know a better way I'd be happy to listen to it.

*Edit :*
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqfHI.png) an inspector screenshot focuses on the selected elements.

Comment: If the first child is a `null` then just `.appendChild` the `newDiv`.

Comment: @AdamOrłowski : No because it's only when I get my element by using js that the element is empty. On the webpage the elements have child (I updated my question with a sreen of my inspectore). And I already tried to `.appendChild` and the div was at the bottom of my container.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with timing. The element is empty when you grab it and filled after that. Maybe you need to wait for "some time". Make a test - try to grab `item` after couple of seconds by `setTimeout`

Comment: @AdamOrłowski The timing was the issue. I put a `setTimeout` on all that part (`queryselector` and `insertBefore`) and that work ! Thank you !

Comment: Can I make a few points out of this? I will post the answer. If you can mark it as good answer it'd be great :)

Comment: @AdamOrłowski done ! Thank you again ! (I haven't enough point to upvote your answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an issue with timing. The element is empty when you grab it and filled after that.

Maybe you need to wait for "some time".

Try to grab `item` after couple of seconds by setting the timeout (`setTimeout`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the the element you're targetting has a child element? If it does not, .firstChild will return null.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I will update my post with an inspector screenshot.